# What was RD-180 used in, before Atlas III/V?

Tags: rockets, engines, rd-180, atlas-v

At NasaSpaceFlight.com, Chris Gerbhart [writes](http://www.nasaspaceflight.com/2014/11/atk-expand-alternative-atlasv-rd-180/):

> The RD-180 has provided exceptional performance to the Atlas V and was chosen to be the engine of the first stage in no small part because of its safety record and reliable performance track record.

Who flew the RD-180 before it was used on Atlas III? They flew 6 Atlas III flights, and then transitioned to the Atlas V.

Ya, the bigger brother RD-170 was flown on Energia on the side boosters and became the standalone Zenit booster.  But who else flew the RD-180, to give it a track record before the Atlas V?

If as Wikipedia suggests that the Atlas III was the first use of the RD-170, then what was the Russian intent in developing it from the RD-170 core?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RD-180), RD-180 has only been used on the Atlas line, so I would assume they're talking about the track record of the whole RD-170 family -- the Energia and Zenit applications in particular.

Comment: I suspect the author did not mean what he wrote.  :)  Zenit has not had such a great history, and two launches of Energia does not a track record make.

Comment: Agree that it's a bit of a reach, but looking at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Zenit_launches, something like 41 of 43 Zenit launches prior to 2002, including test flights, did not have first-stage engine problems. That second stage, tho...